# How to prove $f(x)=x^4$ is concave up by definition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, factoring, symmetric-polynomials

I know $f(x)=x^4$ is concave up, by calculating its second derivative. However, how to prove that $f(x)=x^4$ is concave up by definition, say $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})<(1/2)f(x_1)+(1/2)f(x_2)$ for all $x_1,~x_2$? I'd tried binomial theorem, but can't get anything.

Comment: That's not the definition of concavity that I'm familiar with. For continuous functions it seems to be equivalent, but in general I don't think it is.

Comment: @Arthur It is an antiquated definition (as far as I know introduced in that form by Otto Stolz in the 19th century). For continuous functions it is definitely equivalent to the "modern" definition. Although I do not have an example, I know that for non-continuous functions it is in general wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an intermediate step, use the inequality

$$ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \ge \left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2 $$

which is relatively easy to prove.

This gives

$$ \frac{x^4 + y^4}{2} = \frac{(x^2)^2 + (y^2)^2}{2} \ge \left(\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}\right)^2 \ge \left(\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 = \left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^4. $$

---

Alternatively, using the "usual" definition of convexity, we have

$$ [(1 - \lambda)x^2 + \lambda y^2] - [(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y]^2 = (1 - \lambda)\lambda (x - y)^2 \ge 0. $$

Being a quadratic form, this is an easy enough sum of squares to compute. One can do it by hand even. Then we do what we did above:

$$ (1 - \lambda)x^4 + \lambda y^4 \ge [(1 - \lambda)x^2 + \lambda y^2]^2 \ge [(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y]^4 . $$

Comment: Sorry, but how to show that $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \ge \left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2$..?

Comment: @Shara See the third line of equations (where $\lambda = \frac12$)

Comment: Shara: evaluate the parenthesis on the right hand side and then rearrange the terms to get that this inequality is in fact equivalent to $(x-y)^2\geq 0$

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean that $f$ is a convex function.

Id est, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^4$$ or
$$8(a^4+b^4)\geq a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4$$ or
$$7a^4-4a^3b-6a^2b^2-4ab^3+7b^4\geq0$$ or
$$7a^4-14a^3b+7a^2b^2+10a^3b-20a^2b^2+10ab^3+7a^2b^2-14ab^3+7b^4\geq0$$ or
$$(a-b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)\geq0$$ or
$$(a-b)^2(2a^2+2b^2+5(a+b)^2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: You should point out that midpoint-convexity implies ordinary convexity, which isn't exactly a trivial matter.

Comment: OP means exactly what he says -- concave up. The terms "concave up" and "concave down" are superior to "convex" and "concave", in my opinion, 
 because the meaning is immediately obvious in the former case and reliant on arbitrary definition in the latter.

Comment: @Umberto P I know this point, but the topic starter wanted a proof, which I wrote. See please better the topic starter's words. If you wish I am ready to prove the Jensen inequality for this function.

Comment: @MPW It's depend on definition. I just like the word "convex" instead "concave up"

Comment: Understood. It does have the advantage of being a single word, so one may speak of "convexity" rather than the perhaps awkward "upward concavity"

Comment: How do you know it can be factored like this? How to think about it? Is there any clue?

Comment: @Shara Because the inequality is symmetric and the equality occurs for $a=b$. It says that there is a factor $a-b$, which breaks the symmetry, which says that it should be $(a-b)^2$.

Comment: concave (c)up :)